# Help on calculating this integral and changing variables

Tags: integration, change-of-variable

Calculate the integral $I=\iint_D e^\frac{x^3+y^3}{xy}dA$ where D is the surface bounded by $x=y^2$,$x^2=y$ and $x^2=2y$.

Attempt: Let $u=\frac{x^2}{y}$ and $v=\frac{y^2}{x}$. Then we have $1≤u≤2$ and $0≤v≤1$.

$$\frac{∂(u,v)}{∂(x,y)}=A = \begin{vmatrix} \frac{2x}{y} & -\frac{x^2}{y^2} \\-\frac{y^2}{x^2} & \frac{2y}{x} \end{vmatrix}
\quad=3⇒\frac{∂(x,y)}{∂(v,u)}=\frac{1}{3}$$
$$I=\frac{1}{3}\int\limits_{1}^{2}du\int\limits_{0}^{1}e^{u+v}dv=\frac{1}{3}\int_{1}^{2}e^udu\int\limits_{0}^{1}e^vdv$$

Now how should I continue this? Is my approach correct?

Comment: No. If you wanted the integrand to have a $u+v$, then the definitions of your variables are upside down.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Yes I edited that. silly mistake :(

Comment: In that case you should accept my answer instead of editing your post with the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using $u = \frac{x^2}{y}$ and $v = \frac{y^2}{x}$ instead we get a Jacobian of $\frac{1}{3}$ by the same process. The boundaries convert into constants:

$$\begin{cases} y = x^2 \\ 2y = x^2 \\ x = y^2 \\ \end{cases} \implies \begin{cases} u = 1 \\ u = 2 \\ v = 1 \\ \end{cases}$$

However, this does not define a closed region. Given that the original region of integration was strictly in the first quadrant, $v > 0$ which means our last choice of bounds for $v$ could either be some function above or below the line $v = 1$ in the $uv$ plane.

Taking into account that the origin in the $xy$ plane is where the two $u$ curves intersect, we have that

$$uv = xy = 0$$

which is the equation for the axes exactly (a degenerate hyperbola). Thus the missing boundary could either be $u=0$ or $v=0$, but only $v=0$ fits the region (the curves for $0\leq u \leq 1$ aren't between the two parabolas in the $xy$ plane, but the curves for $0\leq v \leq 1$ are). Thus the integral becomes

$$\frac{1}{3} \int_0^1 \int_1^2 e^{u+v}\:du\:dv = \frac{e(e-1)^2}{3}$$